# Reference 'column_name' is ambiguous in SparkSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, apache-spark

I am new to both Spark and SQL. I am trying to execute a sql query using Spark Scala.
Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT 
        a.*
    FROM
    (   SELECT 
                a1.id_bu,
                a1.nama,
                a1.id_Bentuk_bu,
                a1.id_bentuk_usaha,
                a1.id_Jenis_bu,
                a1.id_Jenis_bu_kbli,
                a1.alamat,
                a1.kodepos,
                a1.telepon,
                a1.fax,
                a1.email,
                a1.website,
                a1.id_kabupaten,
                a1.id_propinsi,
                a1.npwp,
                a1.no_spt as modal_dasar,
                a1.log,
                a2.bu_nomor
            FROM 
                bu a1,
                bu_nomor a2
            where
                    a1.id_bu = a2.id_bu
                AND a1.id_propinsi = a2.id_propinsi 
    ) as a,
    
    ( SELECT 
            b.id_bu,
            b.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
            b.kualifikasi_kbli,
            b.id_asosiasi_bu,
            b.propinsi,
            b.tgl_permohonan,
            c.tgl_habis
        FROM
            ( SELECT 
                    b1.id_bu,
                    b1.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
                    b1.kualifikasi_kbli,
                    b1.id_asosiasi_bu,
                    b1.propinsi,
                    b1.tgl_permohonan
                FROM 
                    bu_registrasi_history_kbli b1
                WHERE 
                        b1.id_status = '4'
                    AND b1.tgl_proses < '2018-03-01' ) as b,
            ( SELECT 
                    c1.id_bu,
                    c1.id_klasifikasi,
                    c1.id_asosiasi_bu,
                    c1.tgl_habis
                FROM 
                    bu_sbu_kbli c1
                WHERE 
                    c1.tgl_habis >= '2018-03-01' ) as c
        WHERE 
                b.id_bu = c.id_bu
            AND SUBSTR( b.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli, 1, 3) = c.id_klasifikasi
            AND b.id_asosiasi_bu = c.id_asosiasi_bu
    UNION all 
    SELECT 
            d.id_bu,
            d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
            d.kualifikasi_kbli,
            d.id_asosiasi_bu,
            d.propinsi,
            d.tgl_permohonan,
            e.tgl_habis
        FROM
            ( SELECT 
                    d1.id_bu,
                    d1.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
                    d1.kualifikasi_kbli,
                    d1.id_asosiasi_bu,
                    d1.propinsi,
                    d1.tgl_permohonan
                FROM 
                    bu_registrasi_history_kbli_hapus d1
                WHERE 
                        d1.id_status='4'
                    AND d1.tgl_proses<'2018-03-01' ) as d,
            ( SELECT 
                    e1.id_bu,
                    e1.id_klasifikasi,
                    e1.id_asosiasi_bu,
                    e1.tgl_habis
                FROM 
                    bu_sbu_kbli_hapus e1
                WHERE
                    e1.tgl_habis >= '2018-03-01' ) as e
        WHERE 
                d.id_bu = e.id_bu
            AND SUBSTR( d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli, 1, 3) = e.id_klasifikasi
            AND d.id_asosiasi_bu = e.id_asosiasi_bu
        GROUP BY 
            id_bu,
            id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli
        ORDER BY 
            tgl_habis,
            tgl_permohonan DESC) x1
    WHERE 
        a.id_bu = x1.id_bu
    GROUP BY 
        x1.id_bu
```

I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'id_bu' is ambiguous, could be: d.id_bu, e.id_bu.; line 81 pos 12
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:213)
```

I am not sure what the error is about? Is it about two columns with the same name? If i try to use d.id_bu and d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli as suggested in the error in that second last GroupBy it says:

```
'd.`kualifikasi_kbli`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;
Aggregate [id_bu#21], [id_bu#1, nama#2, id_Bentuk_bu#3, id_bentuk_usaha#4, id_Jenis_bu#5, id_Jenis_bu_kbli#6, alamat#7, kodepos#8, telepon#9, fax#10, email#11, website#12, id_kabupaten#13, id_propinsi#14, npwp#15, modal_dasar#0, log#17, bu_nomor#19]
```

Any idea how i can solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Both errors are very clear and you should not be using a group by without aggregate functions I suggest you try DISTINCT instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the table in your group by clause

Answer (score 1):

After going through your query and reformatting for better readability and knowing what was in all the select sub queries and unions, I found that the error refers to the (as stated) GROUP BY CLAUSE where you are joining your "d" and "e" tables.  Since both have the id_bu, you just need to qualify as either

d.id_bu

or

e.id_bu

But because this is part of a UNION SELECT ALL, it could also be your "b" or "c" alias as well.

Next is the non-aggregate error.  In order to use a group by, you must specify the columns you want grouped.  In this case, you are grouping by two columns, but you are returning

```
d.id_bu,
d.id_sub_klasifikasi_kbli,
d.kualifikasi_kbli,
d.id_asosiasi_bu,
d.propinsi,
d.tgl_permohonan,
e.tgl_habis
```

So, you need to identify how to apply a min, max, avg, or other aggregate to the NON-group columns.  If the remaining 5 can change, do you make them each MIN(), or MAX() just so they return, or do you add all of them to your group by.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a basic SQL error, nothing Scala- or Spark-specific
In this clause

```
GROUP BY 
            id_bu
```

Here you have to specify the alias of the sub-query by which you want to group: `group by d.id_bu` or `group by e.id_bu`.